# VueJS with FullCalendar: load fullCalendar ONLY after linking scripts in index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, fullcalendar

I want to load fullCalendar into my Vue component but I get the error "fullCalendar is not a function". It seems as if all the scripts that I load in my index.html file are loaded after the Vue component is loaded

In my index.html file I have loaded the moment.min.js, jquery.min.js, and fullcalendar.min.js.

In my Calendar.vue, I have

```
export default {

    mounted () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({})
    }

}
```

The $ would not be available unless I explicitly do "import $ from 'jquery'", which suggests that the scripts in index.html file do not load until after the component.

How do I solve this problem?

ADDITIONAL DETAILS: I am using Webpack with VueJS provided by https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack and am thus using the VueJS npm module, while the jquery, moment and fullcalendar libraries are all from CDN's linked from my index.html.

Comment: is Vue.js loaded after the other JS files (e.g. as in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/diemah77/pen/gaRKQq))?

Comment: not sure, where are you doing the  <script src=""> and howd u get it to load after the JS files?

Comment: perhaps viewing source on [this view](https://s.codepen.io/diemah77/fullpage/gaRKQq?) would be simpler to see the order. BTW I didn't create that example - just found it by searching the web

Comment: could you post the link here to where you found it plz?

Comment: It was found [here](http://vuejsexamples.com/fullcalendar-vue-component/) on vuejsexamples.com.

Comment: still not sure, the source doesn't say they load fullCalendar script :(

Comment: here- check out [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/sgGbd)

Comment: i updated my post providing some additional details on my vuejs setup

Answer (score 1):

A nice solution is to use vue-full-calendar
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-full-calendar

It generate the same behavior, if we addn't the following line in order to define the jquery "$" :

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have no other problem that makes your `fullCalendar` function undefined, you should be easily able to get it to work. As your bundle does not contains jQuery you can just specify that your bundle should be loaded last, either by:

- Putting the script tag at the end of your body
- Or using it anywhere but with the defer property: `<script src="bundle.js" defer></script>`
- Or packing your relevant code into `window.onload = () => { //Instanciate here your new Vue() };` (also work if your jQuery is included into your bundle!)

Comment: there is no bundle.js file that I can load in index.html, seems like webpack does it automatically when it compiles everything to app.js

Comment: the weird thing is when i look at page source, it loads it at the end of the body, after i load moment, jquery and fullcalendar, so not sure why it still giving me error

Answer (score 0):

Only way working for me is to import $ from 'jquery' and require('fullcalendar')